# Will this work: Manage ESXi host from a guest on the same system?

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, vsphere-client

I have a VMware ESXi 5.5 standalone installation here and thus need the vSphere Client to mange it. Because vCenter is a. Too complicated for just one host b. too expensive. The client is only available for Windows (God knows why, since the hypervisor is linux based). Most of the boxes round here run on Linux, so I thought I just trow a Win7 VM on the System and access it over some kind of RDP-Client.

Will this work (probably yes)? But more importantly is it a good idea? I have a bit of a bad feeling about it, since it is kind of a "pull my self up by my own bootstraps" attempt.

Thank you for your opinions.

Comment: What kind of licence do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly works, but you should definitely keep some other means of accessing it around...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work  But you have to connent that VM network to the management network.

You could use the cli via SSH AS othet means to acces the ESXi Server.

You should also put that VM into the autostart list, so you do not have to start it manually.